# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to use hibernate 3.5.1 final in a swing application
and here are the jars I'm using:

- **hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final**
- **hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.1-Final**
- **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final**
- **hibernate-annotations-3.5.1-Final**
- **hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final**
- **dom4j-1.6.1**
- **slf4j-api-1.6.4**
- **slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4**

When I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Comment: If you're trying to use symbolic links to attach your jar files, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240776/symlinking-tomcat-8-directory-resources

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You also need to include the Log4J JAR file in the classpath.

Note that `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` is only an adapter to make it possible to use Log4J via the SLF4J API. It does not contain the actual implementation of Log4J.

Comment: can you please tell me the maven dependency compatible with the version i am using ?

Comment: well i just needed **log4j-1.2.16.jar**

Comment: adding log4j-1.2.16.jar also solved the problem in my case but slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar didn't

Comment: actually adding maven dependency as such was not sufficient in my case, i also had to add the flag: <scope>build</scope> to make it run:  <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>build</scope>
      </dependency>

Answer (score 5):

You need to download [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) and add in your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

In my environment, I just added the two files to class path. And is work fine.

```
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in October 2019. I didn't even need the `log` jar, the `slf4j-jdk` took care of it.

Comment: This worked for me today oct 20th 2023. Except that my two files are of higher versions.