# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level Exception

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I have met with the following exception and it's the first time I came across with this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<clinit>(JobConf.java:357) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:95) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:79) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:74) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:790) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2812) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2802) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2668) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:355) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.findInitFiles(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:110) ~[spring-data-hadoop-store-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.initOutputContext(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:93) ~[spring-data-hadoop-store-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.onInit(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:83) ~[spring-data-hadoop-store-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.LifecycleObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(LifecycleObjectSupport.java:67) ~[spring-data-hadoop-store-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

I have tried [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-219). But it doesn't solves the problem. Also looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585656/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-log4j-level) and it too disappointed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: at it seems to be a maven project, what is the result of mvn dependency:tree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this issue. It's all because of a wrong code placed in `build.gradle` as

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
 }
```

Removed this and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the class:

> org.apache.log4j.Level

can't be found in your classpath. 
First, make sure that Log4j dependency is in your local repository, i.e. in your .m2 folder, if it's not there, execute on your command-line:

`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`

That Maven command will pull down your requested dependencies which aren't found in your local repository.