# Configure sessionFactory in hibernate in standalone application

Tags: java, hibernate, sax, saxparseexception

i am trying to make a 3rd party simple standalone/swing application that uses hibernate to connect on database for another application, so here's what i did:

**1- Jars used:**

```
hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.1-Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final
hibernate-annotations-3.5.1-Final
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final
dom4j-1.6.1
slf4j-api-1.6.4
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4
log4j-1.2.16.jar
commons-collections-3.2
jta-1.1
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14 (or compatible connector with your DB)
commons-logging-1.1.1
commons-collections-3.2
```

**2- hibernate.cfg.xml (it's inside the src folder):**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>

            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="format_sql">true</property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myapp</property>
            <property name="connection.username">myuser</property>
            <property name="connection.password">mypass</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**3- SessionFactoryHelper:**

```
public class SessionFactoryHelper {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            /*
             * Build a SessionFactory object from session-factory configuration
             * defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml file. In this file we register
             * the JDBC connection information, connection pool, the hibernate
             * dialect that we used and the mapping to our hbm.xml file for each
             * POJO (Plain Old Java Object).
             */
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Error in creating SessionFactory object."
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * A static method for other application to get SessionFactory object
     * initialized in this helper class.
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**4- Sample Query:**

```
Session session = SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    int count = (Integer) session.createSQLQuery(
            "select count(*) from users").uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Users Count: " + count);
```

when running the application, i gets the following exception:

```
Error in creating SessionFactory object.invalid configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.SessionFactoryHelper.<clinit>(SessionFactoryHelper.java:24)
    at com.myapp.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1579)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    at com.xeno.xecamp.desktopManagement.SessionFactoryHelper.<clinit>(SessionFactoryHelper.java:19)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1576)
    ... 4 more
```

can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to Hibernate at all but to the XML structure.

The SAX Reader is set by Hibernate to use validation [(org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper#createSAXReader(String,List,EntityResolver)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/util/XMLHelper.html#createSAXReader%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20org.xml.sax.EntityResolver%29)

It goes more less like this:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Java dosc says

Method setValidating(boolean) - equests DTD validation and causes a failure if no DTD exists. If you only want schema validation and not DTD validation then use setValidating(false).

Your error says clear:

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.`

[In this tutorial you will find all required information about hibernate conf file.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

to fix it you will need to add:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare any DTD in hibernate.cfg.xml

> ```
> The message is saying that you are trying to validate the document, but no DTD has been declared, because no DOCTYPE declaration is present.
> ```