# org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate when run the following code it shows mapping exception how can correct couuld any one guide me. I am using eclipse IDE

My main class

```
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
        userDetails.setUserId(1);
        userDetails.setUserName("Anand");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 
        Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userDetails);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping class="classes.UserDetails"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

UserDetails.java

```
package classes;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose with the information you've given.  Show us the exception stacktrace and the code of your `UserDetails` class.

Comment: I have same problem now!!

Answer (score 0):

Below xml is sample configuration file from [Hibernate Community Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <!-- a SessionFactory instance listed as /jndi/name -->
    <session-factory
        name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">

        <!-- properties -->
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDB</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
        </property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Item.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Bid.hbm.xml"/>

        <!-- cache settings -->
        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Item" usage="read-write"/>
        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Bid" usage="read-only"/>
        <collection-cache collection="org.hibernate.auction.Item.bids" usage="read-write"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I referenced from [answer of @Vash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586512/configure-sessionfactory-in-hibernate-in-standalone-application/10586765#10586765).

I hope this will help to solve your problem.