# Using dynamic where clause in Java JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Using Java 11 and JDBC.
Having PostgreSQL table "employee":

[image]

I need to have an ability to select data, but I don't know in advance, what WHERE conditions would be used.

It could be:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE job_name='PRESIDENT';
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE job_name='PRESIDENT' OR salary>6000;
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary<5000 AND manager_id=68319;
```

Writing all possible SQL in the code, would take a lot of time.

Probably, there is some library, that already has implementation for it.

Comment: Maybe do something like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21807974/5515060)?

Comment: you can consider to use jpa. It help to map tables to java entities and help to reduce native query like this

Comment: @SoT doesn't JPA require Spring to run? That may be a lot of overhead when solely wanting to simplify some SQL queries

Comment: @Artur are you writing a web app or desktop app?
If desktop, refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582586/how-to-configure-hibernate-in-standalone-swing-application-in-eclipse

Comment: When do you know what whereclause you need? You can build your SQL-Statements as string with dynamic where clauses. But use Parameters for your variables. You don't need Spring for JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sqlBuilder [http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html]. it has support to build dynamic where clauses based on condition. something like below

```
  var query = SQL
  .SELECT("*")
  .FROM("employee")
  .WHERE()
  ._If(job_name=="PRESIDENT", "job_name = {0}", job_name)

  .ORDER_BY("job_name");
```